# Liberty : Intermediate context does not exist : jms/xyz

Tags: server, ibm-mq, websphere-liberty

I am working on migrating ear application to liberty. It is a web appliation that uses JMS with MQ messaging provider.

For example in my stage.config.xml, we have following properties:

```
MQQueue(0).CCSID 
MQQueue(0).baseQueueName 
MQQueue(0).jndiName 
MQQueue(0).name 
MQQueueConnectionFactory(0).CCSID 
MQQueueConnectionFactory(0).channel 
MQQueueConnectionFactory(0).connectionPool.ConnectionPool(0).maxConnections 
MQQueueConnectionFactory(0).description 
MQQueueConnectionFactory(0).host 
MQQueueConnectionFactory(0).jndiName 
MQQueueConnectionFactory(0).name
MQQueueConnectionFactory(0).port
MQQueueConnectionFactory(0).provider
MQQueueConnectionFactory(0).queueManager
MQQueueConnectionFactory(0).sessionPool.ConnectionPool(0).maxConnections
MQQueueConnectionFactory(0).transportType
```

```
<featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.1</feature>
        <feature>samlWeb-2.0</feature>
        <feature>wasJmsClient-2.0</feature>
        <feature>wasJmsClient-1.1</feature>
         <feature>wmqJmsClient-1.1</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jmsMdb-3.1</feature>
 
    </featureManager>
    
    <featureManager>
         <exclude>jsf-2.2</exclude>
    </featureManager>
    
    <variable name="wmqJmsClient.rar.location"                    
      value="${server.config.dir}/wmq/wmq.jmsra.rar"/>
      
   <jmsQueue id="1533A.TRANSPORT.ASSIGNMENT.RESP" jndiName="jms/xyz/queue/transportAssignment/response"></jmsQueue>
  <jmsQueue id="1533A.TRANSPORT.ASSIGNMENT.RQST" jndiName="jms/xyz/queue/transportAssignment/request"></jmsQueue>
  <jmsQueueConnectionFactory jndiName="jms/xyz" id="xyz_qa_QCF">
    <connectionManager maxPoolSize="10"/>
    <properties.wmqJms providerVersion="unspecified" transportType="CLIENT" applicationName="xyz" channel="CLIENTS.xyz" hostName="host123.GOT.hst.NET" queueManager="xyz141Q" CCSID="1208"/>
  </jmsQueueConnectionFactory>
```

Exception I get : NameNotFoundException: Intermediate context does not exist: jms/xyz

Can anyone please guide on what all parameters/Configurations I have to use in Server.xml for this to work.Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with your `server.xml`:

- duplicated `jndi-1.0` feature
- mixed `wasJmsClient` and `wmqJmsClient` - if you only use `mq` than remove `was`
- mixed versions of `wasJmsClient` - use only one if you need to connect to internal queues also
- `<exclude>` in features - where did you find such construct, I do not believe it is supported
- finally you are using `jms\xyz` once as QCF name, and once as context name. It is incorrect. Change your QCF jndi name to something differnet e.g. `jms\xyz\qcf`

UPDATE based on comments
Check how you are using JMS classes.

Here is config and code I used for connecting to MQ:

`server.xml` fragment:

```
    <feature>jms-2.0</feature>
```

Java code to send message:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class JMSHelper {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(JMSHelper.class.getName());
    
    @Inject
    @JMSConnectionFactory("jms/myapp/NotificationQueueConnectionFactory")
    private JMSContext jmsContext;
    
    @Resource(lookup = "jms/myapp/NotificationQueue")
    private Queue queue;
    
    @Transactional
    void invokeJMS(Object json) throws JMSException, NamingException {

        String contents = json.toString();
        logger.info("Sending "+contents+" to "+queue.getQueueName());
        jmsContext.createProducer().send(queue, contents);
        logger.info("JMS Message sent successfully!");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hi I have made the required changes.But now my error is as follows: A feature definition cannot be found for the wmqjmsclient-1.1 feature. Try running the command, bin/installUtility install wmqjmsclient-1.1, to install the feature. Alternatively, you can run the command, bin/installUtility install defaultServer, to install all features that are referenced by this configuration.

Comment: I wrote you to remove `wasJmsClient` not `wmqJmsCliet`, as you are connecting to WMQ.

Comment: I removed only wasJmsClient and wmqJmsClient1.1 is still present.But still I get this error.

Comment: I get the following exception : JMSCC0014: It is not valid to call the 'commit' method on a nontransacted session.

Comment: @Padmaja added working code for you. I'm not using wmq nor was client features but just jms-2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you will use the resource adapter, so please start with reading [Liberty and the IBM MQ resource adapter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q120040_.htm) in the IBM documentation.

When you start configuring things like documented by IBM and it still does not work, please post the liberty config and the full exception you get, so we can help you again.

Comment: There is general liberty Cheat Sheet doc [here](https://aguibert.github.io/openliberty-cheat-sheet/#_ibm_mq_client) describing [OpenLiberty](https://openliberty.io) configurations. Section 11.3 provides an IBM MQ example setup for the default [developer configuration](https://developer.ibm.com/components/ibm-mq/series/mq-ready-set-connect) e.g., `DEV.APP.SVRCONN`. You'll find the `wmq.jmsra.rar` in your MQ installation path. e.g., `/opt/mqm/java/lib/jca/wmq.jmsra.rar`. As [@Daniel Steinmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/638413/daniel-steinmann) says, please share any specific config issues.