# Liberty Server :It is not valid to call the 'commit' method on a nontransacted session

Tags: exception, ibm-mq, websphere-liberty

I'm moving from WAS8 to Liberty. Following is my code:

```java
connection = factory.createConnection();
session = connection.createSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

When I run my application it gives error saying:

> `DetailedIllegalStateException: JMSCC0014: It is not valid to call the 'commit' method on a nontransacted session.`

Server.xml

```xml
<variable name="wmqJmsClient.rar.location"                    
  value="${server.config.dir}/wmq/wmq.jmsra.rar"/>

 <jmsConnectionFactory jndiName="jms/xyz/QCF" >
     <properties.wmqJms 
        transportType="CLIENT"
        hostName="host3153.GOT.NET" 
        port="1414"
        channel="CLIENTS.xyz"
        queueManager="host141Q"/>
      <connectionManager maxPoolSize="10"/>
   </jmsConnectionFactory>
  

   <jmsQueue id="jms/queue1" jndiName="jms/xyz/queue/response">
     <properties.wmqJms 
        baseQueueName="host1533A.RESP" 
        baseQueueManagerName="host141Q" CCSID="1208" expiry="APP" failIfQuiesce="true" persistence="APP" priority="APP" putAsyncAllowed="ENABLED" readAheadAllowed="ENABLED" readAheadClosePolicy="ALL" receiveConversion="QMGR" targetClient="JMS" receiveCCSID="1208" />
    </jmsQueue>
    
    <jmsQueue id="jms/queue2" jndiName="jms/xyz/queue/transportAssignment/request">
     <properties.wmqJms 
        baseQueueName="host1533A.RQST" 
        baseQueueManagerName="host141Q" CCSID="1208" expiry="APP" failIfQuiesce="true" persistence="APP" priority="APP" putAsyncAllowed="ENABLED" readAheadAllowed="ENABLED" readAheadClosePolicy="ALL" receiveConversion="QMGR" targetClient="JMS" receiveCCSID="1208" />
    </jmsQueue>
```

Comment: Provide full code example and full stack trace to show exactly how you are using session and in which line there is an exception. Check the piece of code I added in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63353913/3701228

Comment: Edited my code.

Comment: commit/rollback methods are not supported in managed environment - check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60566134/websphere-liberty-jms-sessions-dont-work . You need get rid of these and rewrite your code so it is using global transactoins. The easiest is to annotate method with `@Transactional` as in my example, or wrap your code in statless session bean.

Comment: Also consider using `jms-2.0` api and `JMSContext` instead of manually creating connection and session.